# onchange function to array of input text JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have an array of *input text* they all have the same class, so I want to put an event *OnChange* with jquery to everyone of them.

My HTML code is:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control placementTest" data-mask=''>
```

and my Javascript is:

```
$('.placementTest').each(function() {
            $(this).on('change',function (ev) {
                alert('done it');
            });
        });
```

but it's not working. So, what is wrong?

Comment: does the code run after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Should work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/cet0k4tu/ probably missing DOM ready or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your event must trigger after editing ( same on blur ).

if you need to trigger when user input something try to use about onkey "keydown" "keypress" "keyup" etc. . Example below !

```js
$('.placementTest').each(function() {
            $(this).on('keypress',function (ev) {
                alert('done it');
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
input 1 <input type="text" class="form-control placementTest" data-mask=''>
input 2 <input type="text" class="form-control placementTest" data-mask=''>
input 3 <input type="text" class="form-control placementTest" data-mask=''>
```

P.S. it's work fine !

Answer (score 2):

No Need for `$('.placementTest').each` . Also, with an input, you want the keyup event Just need

```
   $('.placementTest').keyup(function() {
      //do stuff

   })
```

or fire when the user leaves the input:

```
 $('.placementTest').blur(function() {
 //do stuff

 })
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qpu0Lsth/2/

Comment: On a side note, why do you need to listen for change? What are you trying to accomplish? keyup will fire every entry. Do you want it to fire when the user leaves the input and goes to the next one? If so, use the `blur()`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two classes in the markup. Try to use one class